# Sidebar not moving up despite nothing in it's way?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm working on a page located here: http://www.fusionhost.co.uk/newsite2/

I'm trying to get the `right sidebar` that contains "UK Servers, Money Back etc" to move up so it is directly below the `client reviews` box. Using firebug I see that nothing is in the way and it should be moving up without a problem, but it isn't.

It seems to move up and down with the height of the `Fuse with us` box, despite that box's height not covering the portion above it.

Comment: Located where ??? http://www is not a valid location :D

Comment: You need to replace the dot with . sometimes people write links and emails like this to avoid spiders.

Comment: @kmb385: Put `User-agent: *` on one line of a text file, `Disallow: /newsite2` on the next line, save it as robots.txt, and put it in the root of www.fusionhost.co.uk. Now spiders will leave you alone, and we don’t have to type in your URL as a first step to helping you. See http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Comment: Thats a helpful tidbit paul.  I wasn't advocating this as a best practice.  Just explaining what the questioner was doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the welcome and testimonials divs, which are block elements.

if you move the rpanel immediately after testimonials and float it right, the panel will move up.

Comment: @kmb385: No it doesn't. Check out the site now :)

Comment: @Brett, your right I must have got my tags mismatched in firebug.  Glad you got things resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping this style in your css:

Replace this:

```
.rpanel .box {
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    color: #AEAEAE;
    float: left;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 178px;
}
```

With this:

```
.rpanel .box {
    border: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
    color: #AEAEAE;
    float: left;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative; /* ADDED */
    top: -120px; /* ADDED */
    width: 178px;
}
```

Comment: I've thought of doing something like that but was hoping for a solution where it would move itself down automatically if the `client reviews` box got bigger.

Comment: I'm not a css & html expert, I do know some however and I don't see how your going to pull this off without pulling it out of its normal position within the markup.  You should specify that in your question.  With that being said, I'm sure someone can do it.